# Send file with skype4py?

Tags: python, skype4py

How would I go about sending a file over Skype with Skype4Py? I looked through the [docs](http://skype4py.sourceforge.net/doc/html/) but couldn't find out how to do it.

Comment: Huh, http://skype4py.sourceforge.net/ redirects to https://developer.skype.com/wiki/Skype4Py, which 404s.

Comment: yes.. i know i have searched around everywhere without finding an answer :/

Comment: Today there has been a new release: https://github.com/awahlig/skype4py/ I suggest you take a look on unittest for examples. If the necessary API commands are not implemented patches are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at the http://skype4py.sourceforge.net/doc/html/Skype4Py.filetransfer-module.html
module, 
as well as 
http://skype4py.sourceforge.net/doc/html/Skype4Py.client.Client-class.html#OpenFileTransferDialog

Note: I'm having timeout issues trying to use the client class that Skype4Py uses, so if you're able to use that class let me know how you accessed it please.